# System.Web.HttpCookie Cannot be converted to Integer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I can get the logged in users Id but when I try to pass the cookie into the query I am getting the above error. How can I convert the value? In the table the value is (d606e50f-0a5c-42d6-a8eb-4219465e8a5e)

```
        Dim myObject As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
        Dim UserId As String = myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString()

        Dim cookieUser As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("UserId")
        cookieUser.Value = UserId.ToString()
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookieUser)

        Dim DS As DataSet

        DS = U.RunQuery("SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [Phone] from aspnet_Users Where @UserId = "(cookieUser))

    FirstNameTextBox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("FirstName")
    LastNameTextBox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("LastName")
    EmailTextBox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Email")
    PhoneTextBox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Phone")
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following

```
UserId = "(cookieUser)
```

VB.Net is seeing that as a string constant followed by a `(value)` which it treats as an index into the string.  Hence it tries to interpret `cookieUser` as an `Integer` and fails.  It looks like you are trying to concatenate strings here and if so do the following

```
UserId = " & cookieUser
```

Note that this seemingly opens you up to an SQL injection attack though.  It would be much better to use a query builder and sanitize your inputs than using raw string concatenation to build up the SQL queries

Comment: I tried changing that and applying my sanitize method and its saying "The method or operation is not implemented."

Comment: @Frater that sounds like you're hitting a new error at run time vs a compile time error.  You may need to post a new Q for that.  Resolving it will need more info about where the error occurs and possibly the stack traceof the exceptino